# The donut is semi transparent. The icing gets inside the donut. offset & inner is +1

Tags: modeling

[image]
The donut is semi transparent and that can't make me focus ... another problem is that the icing part keeps getting inside the donut when I grab it down. i made sure to snap to face and proportional edit is on. Offset & inner is +1 .. any help ?
Ps: I am following the Blender Guru donut tutorial and I can't find what's wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You have the x-ray mode on, allowing you to see through the object.

Comment: thanks a lot .. sorry but do you have an idea about the second problem ?

Comment: The second problem is literally every body faces , literally , even i faced thats why i skipped this part after a lot of troubleshooting , you can try sculpting or a high viscosity Fluid simulation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0mFLJG_Cyo , try this , CG Geek covers a variety of steps that can be taken that were not discussed by Andrew price

Answer (score 2):

[image]
You need to switch off x-ray mode

Comment: thanks.. it worked